# Author affiliations in achemso class

Tags: achemso, affiliation

I am trying to enter a list of authors and affiliations in a document with achemso class, but I am new to LaTeX and can't figure how for to get the right affiliation with the right person...
There are 5 authors and 6 affiliations:

Author1 (affiliation 1,2,3), Author 2 (affiliation 4,5), Author 3 (affiliation 2,6), Author 4 (affiliation 2,6), Author 5 (affiliation 1,2,3,4)

The list is quite complex and I don't know how to include all of them properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Answer (score 3):

It's just a case of 'fill in the blanks':

```
\documentclass{achemso}

\author{Author1}
\email{author1@place.xyz}
\affiliation{Place 1}
\alsoaffiliation{Place 2}
\alsoaffiliation{Place 3}

\author{Author2}
\affiliation{Place 4}
\alsoaffiliation{Place 5}

\author{Author3}
\affiliation{Place 2}
\alsoaffiliation{Place 6}

\author{Author4}
\affiliation{Place 2}
\alsoaffiliation{Place 6}

\author{Author5}
\affiliation{Place 1}
\alsoaffiliation{Place 2}
\alsoaffiliation{Place 3}
\alsoaffiliation{Place 4}

\title{Some things we did}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```